# parse name no spaces?

Tags: java

When a user enters more than one space, my program doesn't properly print the user's name out. For example, if the user enters their first name followed by 2 spaces and then their last name, my program assumes those extra spaces are the middle name and prints the middle name as the spaces and the last name as the second string entered, even though only two strings were entered. How can I improve this issue so that the extra space a user may enter doesn't count as a middle or last name?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Welcome to the name parser.\n");
    System.out.print("Enter a name: ");
    String name = sc.nextLine();

    name = name.trim();

    int startSpace = name.indexOf(" ");
    int endSpace = name.indexOflast(" ");
    String firstName = "";
    String middleName = "";
    String lastName = "";

    if(startSpace >= 0)
    {
        firstName = name.substring(0, startSpace);
        if(endSpace > startSpace)
        {
            middleName = name.substring(startSpace + 1, endSpace);
        }
        lastName = name.substring(endSpace + 1, name.length());
    }
    System.out.println("First Name: " + firstName);
    System.out.println("Middle Name: " + middleName);
    System.out.println("Last Name: " + lastName);
}
```

Output: joe        mark

```
First name: joe
Middle name: // This shouldn't print but because the user enter extra spaces after first name the spaces becomes the middle name.
Last name: mark
```

Comment: Why did you ask the same question second time today?

Comment: Will you clarify? I wasn't able to see any significant difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
 // replaceAll needs regex so "\\s+" (for whitespaces)
 // s+ look for one or more whitespaces
 // replaceAll will replace those whitespaces with single whitespace.
 // trim will remove leading and trailing whitespaces

 name = name.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

[1. Java Regex](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

[2. replaceAll API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: You should explain what this does.

Comment: @MattBall Was just doing that. Thanks anyway.